# SQLPlus feedback returns null rows created

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, spool

I've got 4 statements that are being run in SQLPLus and spooled to a file.

To spool to this file I run the following:

```
echo "whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode ROLLBACK" > ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set echo off" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set serveroutput on" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set feedback on" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set pagesize 0" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set heading off" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set linesize 80" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set autocommit off" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set exitcommit off" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set sqlprompt \"$DB_NAME SQL>\"" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set sqlnumber on" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set newpage 0" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "set echo on" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "spool $TMPDIR/$filewoextension.log" >> ${sql_tempfile}
cat ${file} >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "\n" >> ${sql_tempfile}
echo "spool off" >> ${sql_tempfile}

sqlplus / <<-eoSQL

@${sql_tempfile}
```

---

When examining the file, we can see that some of the rows have '100 rows updated.' or '100 rows merged.', but in the very same file, there are some records that show ' rows created.'.

I can't seem to find out why my feedback on some of the statements are being returned as nulls. After this has spooled to a file I use a regular expression to read it, and am having problems thereafter because there is no number being returned from individual statements.

I've tried performing the same thing in a development environment, but don't seem to have the same problem. It only appears to be in our Live environment, and our Oracle DBA's can't identify the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can they at least confirm the behaviour by running the script interactively? I can't see why it would produce the effect you are seeing but `set feedback 1` is safer than `on`.

Comment: Sorry William, I forgot to mention that we have passed the ${sql_tempfile} over to the DBA's and when they run the file in the environment, they get the correct results spooled out.

Comment: Are they running the same sqlplus executable from the same account from the same directory, or just the same database? I was wondering whether there might be some different setting in `login.sql` or `glogin.sql` (though I can't think what), which you wouldn't pick up if you just ran it from TOAD, hence my comment about `set feedback 1`.

Comment: Does `${file}` perhaps include an anonymous PL/SQL block that is doing selective inserts based on some logic and then reporting the number of rows affected using `sql%rowcount`, formatted to mimic what SQL\*Plus would normally show? If the logic meant an insert wasn't actually executed, `sql%rowcount` would be null, so you could get that result. Bit of a long shot, but can't immediately think how else that could happen...

Comment: Just going through some more tests with DBA's William, will post results back here.

Comment: @AlexPoole There isn't a PL/SQL block included in the $file, it's just inserts, updates and merges based of select statements. There isn't any sql%rowcounts in there.

Comment: I assume that means no procedure calls either, even via `exec` (which is just a wrapper around an anonymous block anyway)? Interesting then. Which version of SQL\*Plus is being used in each environment? How many rows should it be reporting in live - essentially, zero or non-zero - and is that the same in dev? Is there are any post-processing of the spooled file before you can look at it - stripping leading zeros, for some reason, later in your script...? Just throwing out random ideas *8-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the LD_LIBRARY_PATH being set to 10.2 rather than 11.2 in one of the profiles that is causing this discrepancy.

Editing the variable to set to the current oracle version seems to fix the problem.